# Import Java library to Scala sbt project

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm trying to use import guava library in SBT project (play framework), but can't compile my code

```
import com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName

class MyClass(link: String) {
  private val domains = {
    val host = new URL(link).getHost
    val domainName = InternetDomainName.from(host)
    domainName.topPrivateDomain().name()
  }
}
```

I get compilation error

```
object google is not a member of package com
```

Can anyone explain, what is the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you added the guava library as a library dependency to your `build.sbt` file? You can find that file in the project's root directory. There you can add the dependency to the guava library:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "17.0",
  // other dependencies separated by commas
)
```

Comment: I added this dependency to project/plugins.sbt.  Adding this to build.sbt resolved the problem.  Can you explain, what happened, please?

Comment: Hmm what languages and build systems do you know so far? Specifying this in the `build.sbt` file, causes the play application to download this dependency/library from the internet. The library is then added to the so called classpath of your application. Only things that are on the classpath may be used in your application by using `import` in your source files.

Comment: Was this explanation understandable? :-)